# Measurable Function and Inverse Maps

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Every text I read about random variables starts by introducing the concept of measurable functions. It goes something like this:

Suppose you have 2 measurable spaces $(\Omega, \Gamma)$ and $(\Omega', \Gamma')$, and you have the following function: $X:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega'$. Then $X$ determines a function:

$$ X^{-1}: \Gamma' \rightarrow \Gamma $$

defined by

$$ X^{-1}(A') = \{ \omega \in\Omega: X(\omega) \in A' \} $$

for $A' \subset \Gamma'$

My question is: Why does this definition of inverse map makes sense? We are defining $X$ on the sets $\Omega, \Omega'$ but the inverse is defined on the $\sigma$-algebras $\Gamma', \Gamma$. It would seem intuitive to me that the definition of the inverse would be on the same sets as $X$. e.g: $X^{-1}:\Omega' \rightarrow \Omega$.

I think the following example explains my confusion:
Imagine $\Omega = \{a,b,c,d\}$, with $\Gamma = \{ \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{c,d\},  \Omega\}$, and $\Omega' = \{1,2,3,4\}$, with $\Gamma' = \{ \emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3,4 \}, \Omega\}$ and let $X(a)=1,X(b)=2, X(c)=3, X(d)=4$. This so far makes sense, but with the given definition of inverse we can now say: $X^{-1}(\{1,2\}) = \{a,b\}$, disregarding the fact that $X$ was defined as a function that receives and outputs **events** not **sets**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an inverse map.  Even if the point-map $X$ is not invertible, the set-map $X^{-1}$ is defined by the formula $X^{-1}(A') = \{ \omega \in\Omega: X(\omega) \in A' \}$, and it exists.  Perhaps this is confusing notation for beginners.  But it is well-established notation.

Example: $X : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $X(t) = t^2$.  Then for the half-open interval $(2,3]$, we have
$$
X^{-1}\big((2,3]\big) = [-\sqrt3,-\sqrt2) \cup (\sqrt2,\sqrt3] .
$$

---

In an undergaduate textbook of mine I used square-brackets like this $X^{-1}[A']$ for such set-function.  (But, I don't know if that was less confusing for anyone.)